# Accept input attribute doesn't work in chrome for image/jpg format

Tags: html, validation, google-chrome, input

I have the the following input:

```
<input id="multipartFile" name="multipartFile" type="file" class="file" accept="image/jpg,image/png,image/gif,image/bmp,video/mp4,.mov" value="" size="21.5" style="opacity: 0;">
```

I use the following format for working in safari.

but in chrome I see only png files.

Is there way to write that work in both -  safari and chrome ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing `image/` like this `accept=".jpg,.png,.gif,.bmp,.mp4,.mov"`

Since it seems you're only having issues with jpg, if that doesn't work try adding `image/jpeg`.

Comment: Sorry, not sure if this works in safari, cause I can't test it there. Tell me if it works or not.

Comment: I have the same issue)

Comment: You tried both and it still doesn't work in chrome for you?

Comment: i have not iphone right now)  it is working in chrome

Comment: Okay just make a comment later if it doesn't work in safari